# CryptoSwift + CryptoJS making wrong JSON in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, swift2, cryptojs

```
do {
let JSONObject:[String:String] = 
[
"username" : "username",
"password" : "Password",
"domain": "domain"
]
let my64data:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString:Credentials.SecretKey, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)))!

let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

let myString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    // let jsonString = AES1.encrypt(myString!, secretKey: Credentials.SecretKey, options:["iv":my64data])
    // print(" My Encrypted Json = \(jsonString)")
    //            
    // let Decrypt = AES1.decrypt(jsonString, secretKey: Credentials.SecretKey, options: ["iv":my64data])
    //print(" My Decrypted Json = \(Decrypt)")

let iv: Array<UInt8> = AES.randomIV(128/8)
let salt: Array<UInt8> = AES.randomIV(128/8)

let value = try! PKCS5.PBKDF2(password: Credentials.SecretKey.utf8.map({$0}), salt: salt, iterations: 1000, variant: .sha256).calculate()
                value.toHexString()

                _ = CryptoJS.mode.ECB()
                _ = CryptoJS.pad.Iso97971()
                _ = CryptoJS.pad.AnsiX923()
                _ = CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126()
                _ = CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding()

                let encrypted : Array<UInt8>

                     encrypted = try AES(key: value, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).encrypt((myString?.utf8.map({$0}))!)
                    let decrypted = try AES(key: value, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).decrypt(encrypted)

    //            let jsonString = AES1.encrypt(myString!, secretKey: String(value), options:["iv":iv.toHexString(),"mode":CryptoJS.mode().ECB,"padding":CryptoJS.pad().ZeroPadding])
                print(" My Encrypted Json = \(encrypted.toHexString())")
    //            
    //            let pkcs = PKCS7()
    //            
    //            let Decrypt = AES1.decrypt(jsonString, secretKey: String(value), options: ["iv":iv.toHexString(),"mode":CryptoJS.mode().ECB,"padding":pkcs])
               print(" My Decrypted Json = \(decrypted.toHexString())")

                let myInputIV : String = String(iv.toHexString())
                let myInputSalt :String = String(salt.toHexString())

                let finalJSONObject:[String:String] = [

                    "ciphertext" : "\(encrypted.toHexString())",
                    "iv" : "\(myInputIV)",
                    "salt": "\(myInputSalt)"

                ]

    print("Final Json Object = \(finalJSONObject)")

                let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string:"<myURL>")!
                print(requestURL)
                let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
                urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                urlRequest.HTTPBody = try!NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(finalJSONObject, options:.PrettyPrinted)

                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler:{
                    data, response, error -> Void in

                    // Asynchronously call...
                    if (data != nil) {

                        print("Dataaa = \(data!)")

                        self.loginServiceResponse(data!)

                    }else{

                        Singleton.SharedInstance.myAlert(alertTitle:Constants.SERVER_ERROR_TITLE, alertMessage: Constants.SERVER_ERROR_MESSAGE, alertButtonTitle:Constants.OK)
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    }


                })

                task.resume()

            } catch {
                print(error)

            }
```

I got this error:

> Error with Json Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Comment: In postman i got padding error

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Comment: Upate the code with a [mcve], jiust the encryption part wityh inputs and outputs. First get simple encryption to work, then add JSON, then add communications. Build incrementally on working code, the "big bang" approach is hard to debug.

Comment: Compound statements like `AES(key: value, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).encrypt((myString?.utf8.map({$0}))!)` and `AES1.encrypt(myString!, secretKey: String(value), options:["iv":iv.toHexString(),"mode":CryptoJS.mode().ECB,"padding":CryptoJS.pad().ZeroPadding])` are hard to understand and debug since intermediate values are not available. Multiple simpler statements with intermediate variable are easier and just rely on the compiler to optimize the code. Readability is #1 for code.

Comment: @zaph: Do you've any common crypto installation tips? Could you help me in this

Answer (score 0):

To use Common Crypto from Swift

1. Add a bridging header
2. Add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` to the header.

The example uses CBC mode and prefixes the encrypted data with the IV which is a method generally used for handling the IV.

## Example from deprecated documentation section:

AES encryption in CBC mode with a random IV (Swift 3.0)

The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data

`aesCBC128Encrypt` will create a random IV and prefixed to the encrypted code.
`aesCBC128Decrypt` will use the prefixed IV during decryption.

Inputs are the data and key are Data objects. If an encoded form such as Base64 if required convert to and/or from in the calling method.

The key should be exactly 128-bits (16-bytes), 192-bits (24-bytes) or 256-bits (32-bytes) in length. If another key size is used an error will be thrown.

[PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) is set by default.

This example requires Common Crypto
It is necessary to have a bridging header to the project:
`#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`
Add the `Security.framework` to the project.

This is example, not production code.

```
enum AESError: Error {
    case KeyError((String, Int))
    case IVError((String, Int))
    case CryptorError((String, Int))
}

// The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data
func aesCBCEncrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data) throws -> Data {
    let keyLength = keyData.count
    let validKeyLengths = [kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192, kCCKeySizeAES256]
    if (validKeyLengths.contains(keyLength) == false) {
        throw AESError.KeyError(("Invalid key length", keyLength))
    }

    let ivSize = kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    let cryptLength = size_t(ivSize + data.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    var cryptData = Data(count:cryptLength)

    let status = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {ivBytes in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, kCCBlockSizeAES128, ivBytes)
    }
    if (status != 0) {
        throw AESError.IVError(("IV generation failed", Int(status)))
    }

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0
    let options   = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    let cryptStatus = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        cryptBytes,
                        dataBytes, data.count,
                        cryptBytes+kCCBlockSizeAES128, cryptLength,
                        &numBytesEncrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.count = numBytesEncrypted + ivSize
    }
    else {
        throw AESError.CryptorError(("Encryption failed", Int(cryptStatus)))
    }

    return cryptData;
}

// The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data
func aesCBCDecrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data) throws -> Data? {
    let keyLength = keyData.count
    let validKeyLengths = [kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192, kCCKeySizeAES256]
    if (validKeyLengths.contains(keyLength) == false) {
        throw AESError.KeyError(("Invalid key length", keyLength))
    }

    let ivSize = kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    let clearLength = size_t(data.count - ivSize)
    var clearData = Data(count:clearLength)

    var numBytesDecrypted :size_t = 0
    let options   = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    let cryptStatus = clearData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCDecrypt),
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        dataBytes,
                        dataBytes+kCCBlockSizeAES128, clearLength,
                        cryptBytes, clearLength,
                        &numBytesDecrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        clearData.count = numBytesDecrypted
    }
    else {
        throw AESError.CryptorError(("Decryption failed", Int(cryptStatus)))
    }
    
    return clearData;
}
```

Example usage:

```
let clearData = "clearData0123456".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
let keyData   = "keyData890123456".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
print("clearData:   \(clearData as NSData)")
print("keyData:     \(keyData as NSData)")

var cryptData :Data?
do {
    cryptData = try aesCBCEncrypt(data:clearData, keyData:keyData)
    print("cryptData:   \(cryptData! as NSData)")
}
catch (let status) {
    print("Error aesCBCEncrypt: \(status)")
}

let decryptData :Data?
do {
    let decryptData = try aesCBCDecrypt(data:cryptData!, keyData:keyData)
    print("decryptData: \(decryptData! as NSData)")
}
catch (let status) {
    print("Error aesCBCDecrypt: \(status)")
}
```

Example Output:

```
clearData:   <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>
keyData:     <6b657944 61746138 39303132 33343536>
cryptData:   <92c57393 f454d959 5a4d158f 6e1cd3e7 77986ee9 b2970f49 2bafcf1a 8ee9d51a bde49c31 d7780256 71837a61 60fa4be0>
decryptData: <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>
```

Notes:
One typical problem with CBC mode example code is that it leaves the creation and sharing of the random IV to the user. This example includes generation of the IV, prefixed the encrypted data and uses the prefixed IV during decryption. This frees the casual user from the details that are necessary for [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

For security the encrypted data also should have authentication, this example code does not provide that in order to be small and allow better interoperability for other platforms.

Also missing is key derivation of the key from a password, it is suggested that [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) be used is text passwords are used as keying material.

For robust production ready multi-platform encryption code see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor).